# htaccess Apache RewriteRule .asp to .php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use RewriteRule in htaccess to permanently redirect this:

http://www.example.com/store/scripts/prodView.asp?idproduct=240

to

http://www.example.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=50

I have tried:

> Options +FollowSymlinks
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^idproduct=240$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^store/scripts/prodView.asp$ index.php\?route=product/product\&path\=59\&product_id\=50? [L,NC,R=301]

.htaccess is in the root

Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^idproduct=240$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/scripts/prodView\.asp$ index.php?route=product/product\&path=59\&product_id=50 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Without `\?` in RewriteRule url

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Error message ? The index page is not loaded or the wrong link?

Comment: Croises 13, I should have stated this in the original question: the problem is that that browser does not rewrite the URL at all with the (incorrect) old one still in the URL address bar. This results in an error (unable to locate) page being generated. It's as if the htaccess is being ignored but I know it is not as other commands in htaccess are being followed

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with the help of Croises although I don't know the full reason for the problem.

In my original question, for brevity, relevance and clarity, I left out some some RewriteRule code that was lying above the code I was writing. This code was provided by the shopping cart software.

The totality of the RewriteRule code was thus:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

#my code start
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^idproduct=240$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/scripts/prodView\.asp$ index.php?route=product/product\&path=59\&product_id=50 [L,NC,R=301]
#my code end
```

Croises question below got me thinking “why is my code being ignored?”. I therefore put my code above the shopping cart’ RewriteRule code and now it works, although I don’t understand why the other code was interfering with my code.

The code that now works is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#my code start
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^idproduct=240$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^store/scripts/prodView\.asp$ index.php?route=product/product\&path=59\&product_id=50 [L,NC,R=301]
#my code end

#original code
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
#original code
```

I guess I have therefore answered my question but with help from Croises. My apologies for leaving out some important information in the original question