# Redirect ASP page to another (php) page with get parameters

Tags: asp.net, redirect

How can i redirect ASP page to another (php) page ? like this :

http://domain.com/page.aspx?firstname=XXX&lastname=YYY

=> 
http://domain.com/page/?firstname=XXX&lastname=YYY

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857/mod-rewrite-equivalent-for-iis-7-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814768/how-can-i-enable-mod-rewrite-on-iis-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331485/how-to-rewrites-urls-in-asp-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34569973/htaccess-apache-rewriterule-asp-to-php

Comment: `RewriteRule "page1" /page2 [L,NC,R=301]` like this ? but how can i pass the get parameters ?

Comment: I edited my comment with a few more links to consult. You'll need to reload it.